# How to wrap four column into a bootstrap carousel slide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm fetching news headlines from an api service and I'm displaying it using vuejs. I want to use the default [bootstrap 5 carousel](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#crossfade)

At the moment I'm using `col-3` with a `v-for` loop to iterate the results. what I want to achive is to have four columns wrapped in each slide but I don't know how to proceed because bootstrap will manage automatically the columns and will create a new line after four col-3. Is there any good solution?

code for carousel

```
          <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item" :class="{ 'active': index === 0 }" v-for="( news, index ) in newsfeed.articles" :key="index">
                
<!-- here I want to have 4 columns -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue? You want 4 columns and are correcting using `col-3`, are you expecting more and then need to deal with more than 4 columns?

Comment: I wanto four columns in each carousel slide. I'm trying to make something similar to swiper slides group.

Comment: Okay. So why are you concerned about what Bootstrap does *after* your 4th `col-3`. If you're only including 4 of them there should be no issue.  What is the code you're using to attempt to iterate the columns that is resulting in the undesired effect?

Comment: I don't have only four columns, I never writed that. I will have an array that will be iterated using `v-for` and will have a length of minimum 20 elements. I want to show four cols for eachi slide so I can use the navigation arrows to navigate them